# Improved security using Customers API with Transaction API?

Tags: square

I'm currently using the transaction api to create simple, single charges and refunds. We won't be needed recurring billing.

Is there any security benefit to creating a customer profile when using the transaction API?

Other payment providers will look for a datakey or client payment info first on its end rather than accepting post requests with sensitive information.

Comment: Now that I think of it, I can't see any benefit of security since a nonce is sent to the API and not actual credit card info.

Comment: No, there would be no benefit regarding security. There would be benefit in reporting (seeing what customers ordered etc), but no security benefit. Was there an underlying question behind this on why you thought there might be?

Comment: This is the first time I personally have implemented a payment system but the system I'm working on already has 3 other payment systems which flow quite differently.